# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter

Tags: spring, web-services

Hi i am new for WebServices and In my My-Sql Database I have **student** table with some columns those are "**user_id**", and "**name**" and "**marks**"

I want to update one row based on userId for this i wrote below code but i am getting exception like below can some one help me please

```
Controller [com.ensis.sample.controller.SampleController]
Method [public com.ensis.sample.model.StatusObject com.ensis.sample.controller.SampleController.updateStudentListById(int)]

org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter 'userId' is not present
```

### controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public StatusObject updateStudentListById(@RequestParam int userId){
    return userService.updateStudentDetailsById(userId);
}
```

### UserService:-

```
@Transactional
    public StatusObject updateStudentDetailsById(int id){

        Users users = usersdao.updateStudentDetailsById(id);
        if(users!=null){
            users.setName("Sample");
            users.setMarks(99.99);
        }
        StatusObject statusObject = new StatusObject();
        boolean status = usersdao.updateUser(users);
        if(status==true){
            statusObject.setStatus(false);
            statusObject.setMessage("Success");
            return statusObject;
        }else{
            statusObject.setStatus(true);
            statusObject.setMessage("Failure");
            return statusObject;
        }
    }
```

### UserDao:-

```
public Users updateStudentDetailsById(int userId){

        System.out.println("UserId is=====>"+userId);
        String hql = "FROM Users s WHERE " + "s.user_id = :userId";
        Session session  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("user_id", userId);

        List<?>list = query.list();
        Iterator<?>itr = list.iterator();
        if(itr.hasNext()){
            Users users = (Users)itr.next();
            return users;
        }
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        return null;
    }
```

### Users:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Users {

    @Id
    private int user_id;
    private String name;
    private int rank;
    private double marks;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(double marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller? You probably might have missed the userId in the request parameter like "users?userId=XXX".

Comment: Hi @Rossi Robinison i edited my code please see once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Krish, when you are posting something, you usually use Spring's `@RequestBody`as seen below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public StatusObject updateStudentListById(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateStudentDetailsById(userId);
}
```

You need to pass the JSON object to this controller method. Spring will deserialize the JSON for you.

When you say `@RequestParam`, it expects to find the request parameters like 
`/update?userId=1`

**PS**: It is not good practice to send just the ID to update a resource.

Comment: i just want to pass parameters not want to pass json object

Comment: What are you updating on the object? But just to make it work you can do update(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId). And your URL would be like .../update?userId=xxxx

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/WebService-2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [user_id]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [user_id]

Comment: That's your DAO exception. It is not finding the named parameter expected as user_id. change user_id to userId in your DAO at this line: query.setParameter("user_id", userId) --> query.setParameter("userId", userId);

Answer (score 1):

Are you  using it as a RestController.The excecption is coming from the controller as it expects a parameter from the client.Please verify if you are passing the userID in the pathParam.